# Xamarin.Auth authentication issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xamarin.android, asp.net-identity, xamarin.auth

I have a `Xamarin.Android` project and an `ASP.NET MVC 5` website with `ASP.NET Identity and OAuth` for the account management and login.

I have added `Xamarin.Auth` to the `Android` project using the Xamarin components in Visual Studio.

```
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
    clientId: "client id here",
    scope: "scope here",
    authorizeUrl: new Uri(Constants.OAuthAuthorizeUrl),
    redirectUrl: new Uri(Constants.OAuthRedirectUrl)
)
{
    AllowCancel = false
};
```

This is the initialization of the authenticator in the `StartActivity`.

Now the `Completed` event handler:

```
auth.Completed += async (sender, args) =>
{
    if (!args.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            var newIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(LoginActivity));

            StartActivity(newIntent);
        });
    }

    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "ts", DateTime.Now.ToString("ss") } };

    var request = new OAuth2Request("POST", new Uri(Constants.GetCurrentUser), parameters, args.Account);
    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
    var responseText = response.GetResponseText();
}
```

Then I start the Authenticator:

```
var intent = auth.GetUI(this);
StartActivity(intent);
```

The login page shows as expected, I enter credentials and the `Completed` event fires and the Authenticator `IsAuthenticated` value is `true`, as expected.

When I make the request with the `args.Account` (who has the Username empty and I don't know why but the tokens are set) the ASP.NET Website can't Authenticate and I don't know why. The principal has the identity not authenticated but when the authenticator calls the redirect url the Principal is authenticated.

The iOS app, written in `Swift` with `OAuth2Swift` for the `OAuth` authentication works fine.

Comment: I don't understand what your trying to do here. Are you authenticating the android app with an identity provider, getting a token etc. How does the ASP.NET website come into it? Is this to store user accounts? This can be done on the app with the AccountStore as part of Xamarin.Auth.

Comment: The ASP.NET website is configured with ASP.NET Identity and OAuth and I want to authenticate the Android App with the website provider. The AccountStore stores only an already logged Account, if I pass as parameter to the request the ASP.NET Website says it's not authenticated.

Comment: Ah so you want to access some resource from the ASP site , given that you're logged in? Depending on how the ASPNET identity works, you probably need to put the access token, that is returned in the account from xamarin auth, as a bearer in the Authorization header of the rest call.

Comment: This is because If you're trying to use the Xamarin auth Requests feature it may not work. It did not work for me, so I had to do the REST call myself using HttpClient etc